# Anarchists corrupted my barcode!

Tags: cipher, visual, steganography

Somebody corrupted my QR Code.

Can you tell me who did this and when it happened?

[image]

**Hint:**

> https://www.gs1.org/barcodes/2d

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! To clarify, this is a puzzle you created yourself, right?

Comment: @bobble yes it is. It has a single solution in a few steps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My guess: Gabriel Syme corrupted your QR Code on Thursday.

> Taking Sleafars work on the DataMatrix, we get the first hint: G SYME
>
>  I play around some time with the QR Code, trying various approaches (e.g: subtracting the DataMatrix from the QR Code).
>  Eventually I managed to decode the corrupted QR Code to the following Strings: "The Man W} W~nThuúªay", "The Man Wh7 Wlq ThtÌÌÌay".
>  -> The Man ??????? Thursday
>
>  Some search on the internet led to the novel ["The Man Who Was Thursday"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Was_Thursday) by G. K. Chesterton where the main character is an undercover detective called Gabriel Syme

Comment: Well done! The _Anarchists_ part of the title could have saved you some time via searching, but nevertheless I'm impressed you made the effort to decode the corrupted part and how well it worked as a clue.

Answer (score 10):

> If we look at the link provided by the OP, we can see examples for 2 different barcode types: GS1 DataMatrix and GS1 QR Code.
>
>  The barcode in the puzzle looks like a QR code ("concentric" squares in 3 corners), but it can't be decoded. However, if we look more closely, we can see a DataMatrix code in the centre (2 black borders, 2 borders with alternating black/white dots):
>
>  [image: Barcode]
>
>  This one can be decoded to the string **G SYME**.
>
>  My best guess is, that [G. Syme](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/G._Syme) corrupted the barcode in 1949 (based in the info in the link).
>
>  Note: There are more areas in the bottom which look like they could work as DataMatrix codes, but I wasn't able to decode them.

Comment: You're very close.

Comment: I used my employer's barcode app on my phone. It read the QR code as `4539` after some tweaking. Otherwise, it agrees with the decoding you have in your answer.

Comment: @flinty I assume this means, that the time is wrong?

Comment: @Sleafar yes and the person (not the name) is wrong. But you've taken the right steps so far.

Comment: OK, I also got a `1583` out of it, mostly by rotating. This makes me think it is unintended.

Comment: @JoelRondeau Neither of the numbers together with "dr who" gives anything useful on google. I guess I'll have to wait for another inspiration (or another puzzler) to progress further.

Comment: @Sleafar yes I didn't anticipate the dr who reference - I must be too old fashioned - but there is enough info in the question to get the answer. And the _QR_ code should provide confirmation.

Comment: @flinty Do you mean that dr who is a coincidence, and not part of the puzzle?

Comment: @Sleafar It's a coincidence.